# Twilio - phone number verification on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, twilio, ruby-on-rails-5

I have done a phone number verification via Twilio, but I can't find a way how to implement a feature that sends pin code again (if user didn't received it) but also does it not more that 3 times (so users couldn't keep sending codes over and over again). Also, my code looks a bit anti-pattern, so feel free to suggest a better implementation.

When Devise User registers itself, I send him to create a `Profile` that `belongs_to` User. `Profile` holds all user info (and phone number). Here is the form:

```
<%= form_for @profile, remote: true do |f| %>

  <%= f.label 'Your name' %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label 'Phone number' %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :phone, class: 'form-control' %>
  </br>
  <div id="hideAfterSubmit">
    <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block' %>
  </div>

<% end %>

<div id="verify-pin">
<h3>Enter your PIN</h3>
<%= form_tag profiles_verify_path, remote: true do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :pin %>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag "Verify PIN", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div id="status-box" class="alert alert-success">
  <p id="status-message">Status: Haven’t done anything yet</p>
</div>
```

`#verify-pin` and `#status-box` are `display: none`. I unhide them with responding `create.js.erb`.

Create action:

```
  def create
    if user_signed_in? && current_user.profile
      redirect_to profile_path(current_user), notice: 'Jūs jau sukūrėte paskyrą'
    else     
      @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
      @phone_number = params[:profile][:phone]
      @profile.user_id = current_user.id

      SmsTool.generate_pin
      SmsTool.send_pin(phone_number: @phone_number)

      if @profile.save
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js 
        end
      else
        render :new 
      end
    end
  end
```

So at this point profile been created, saved and pin code generated and sent to phone number that user just added.

SmsTool:

```
def self.generate_pin
  @@pin = rand(0000..9999).to_s.rjust(4, "0")
  puts "#{@@pin}, Generated"
end    

def self.send_pin(phone_number:)
  @client.messages.create(
    from: ENV['TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER'],
    to: "+370#{phone_number}",
    body: "Your pin is #{@@pin}"
  )
end   

def self.verify(entered_pin)
  puts "#{@@pin}, pin #{entered_pin} entered"
  if @@pin == entered_pin
    Current.user.profile.update(verified: true) 
  else
    return
  end
end
```

And `Profiles#verify` :

```
  def verify
    SmsTool.verify(params[:pin])
    @profile = current_user.profile     

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end

    if @profile.verified
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Account created'
    end           
  end
```

So what I dont like is SmsTool - as you see I use class variable - couldn't find another way. Also I created a separate Current module just to access Devise `current_user` object.. :

```
module Current
  thread_mattr_accessor :user
end
```

ApplicationController:

```
  around_action :set_current_user

  def set_current_user
    Current.user = current_user
    yield
  ensure
    # to address the thread variable leak issues in Puma/Thin webserver
    Current.user = nil
  end
```

And as I mentioned above - I can't find a way how to implement a feature that sends pin code again (if user didn't received it).

And please - feel free to suggest elegant implementations.

p.s. this is my longest post yet. Sorry for that, but I think all info was needed to show you.

**UPDATE:**

So to resend pin was easy, I just added:

```
  <div id="hiddenUnlessWrongPin">
    <%= button_to "Re-send pin", action: "send_pin_again" %>
  </div>
```

and action:

```
  def send_pin_again
    @phone_number = current_user.profile.phone
    SmsTool.generate_pin
    SmsTool.send_pin(phone_number: @phone_number)
  end
```

But I still don't know how to stop sending pin if user already sent three of them. Only way I see is to make new row in db with integer value and increment it every time user sends pin. Is it the only way?

Comment: To re-send pin I just created a separate action, but its so DRY and all looks a bit messy. So still hoping for nice implementations. otherwise will delete in few hours

Comment: One thing I spotted is that you call `SmsTool.send_pin(phone_number: @phone_number)` before calling `@profile.save` which means that the pin number is sent even if the record is not valid.

Comment: Oh, thats right, thank you @max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good starting point would be to look at the Devise::Confirmable module which handles email confirmation. What I really like about it is that it models confirmations as a plain old resource.

I would try something similar but with a seperate model as it makes it really easy to add a time based limit.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile
  has_many :activations, through: :profiles
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :activations
end

# columns: 
# - pin [int or string]
# - profile_id [int] - foreign_key
# - confirmed_at [datetime]
class Activation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
  has_one :user, through: :profile
  delegate :phone_number, to: :profile
  authenticate :resend_limit, if: :new_record?
  authenticate :valid_pin, unless: :new_record?
  attr_accessor :response_pin
  after_initialize :set_random_pin!, if: :new_record?

  def set_random_pin!
    self.pin = rand(0000..9999).to_s.rjust(4, "0")
  end

  def resend_limit
    if self.profile.activations.where(created_at: (1.day.ago..Time.now)).count >= 3
      errors.add(:base, 'You have reached the maximum allow number of reminders!')
    end
  end

  def valid_pin
    unless response_pin.present? && response_pin == pin
      errors.add(:response_pin, 'Incorrect pin number')
    end
  end

  def send_sms!
    // @todo add logic to send sms
  end
end
```

Feel free to come up with a better name. Additionally this allows you to use plain old rails validations to handle the logic.

You can then CRUD it like any other resource:

```
devise_scope :user do
  resources :activations, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
end
```

---

```
class ActivationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_profile
  before_action :set_activation, only: [:edit, :update]

  # Form to resend a pin notification.
  # GET /users/activations/new
  def new
    @activation = @profile.phone_authentication.new
  end

  # POST /users/activations/new
  def create
    @activation = @profile.phone_authentication.new
    if @activation.save
      @activation.send_sms!
      redirect_to edit_user_phone_activations_path(@activation)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # Renders form where user enters the activation code
  # GET /users/activations/:id/edit
  def edit
  end

  # confirms the users entered the correct pin number.
  # PATCH /users/activations/:id
  def update
    if @activation.update(update_params)
      # cleans up
      @profile.activations.where.not(id: @activation.id).destroy_all
      redirect_to profile_path(@profile), success: 'Your account was activated'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private 

    def update_params
      params.require(:activation)
            .permit(:response_pin)
            .merge(confirmed_at: Time.now)

    end

    def set_profile
      @profile = current_user.profile
    end

    def set_activation
      @profile.activations.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

app/views/activations/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@activation) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit("Send activation to #{@activation.phone_number}") %>
<% end %>

No activation SMS? <%= link_ to "Resend", new_user_activation_path %>
```

app/views/activations/edit.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@activation) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :response_pin %>
  <%= f.submit("Confirm") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This code is just a sketch of how it could be done. Its totally untested and very likely full of errors.

Comment: Thanks, this looks better than mine. I will investigate it. One question - why you create method with exclamation point? `send_sms!`

Comment: In ruby conventions a you use `!` as kind of warning to other developers that the method mutates (changes) the object or can raise an error.

Comment: You could also add a validation so that the activation is only valid for limited time after it is created.

Comment: Hm, thanks. Wonder why I never knew about it.. And yes, I will probably do limited time activation. Thanks for advices, I appreciate!

Comment: No, problem. It was a fun little puzzle.

Comment: I would probably handle actually sending the SMS in a [service object](https://hackernoon.com/service-objects-in-ruby-on-rails-and-you-79ca8a1c946e) that just takes a phone number and pin though. Its a really nice pattern as it gives you a class with a single purpose thats really easy to test in isolation since you don't need to go through the steps of setting up models.

Comment: Hm, never knew about it. Thank you!